# Please tell me about the transfer of tokens created in Solana

Tags: token, blockchain, solana

There are two users.
UserA and UserB

The token created on Solana is called "TokenX".

UserA has some SOL.
UserA got 100 TokenX by airdrop.

UserB has no SOL.
UserB has no TokenX.

UserA and UserB have [Solana SPL Token Wallet].

UserA tried to give UserB 50 TokenX.
However, UserB is **non-assciated** and cannot receive TokenX.
Of course, UserB cannot add TokenX to the wallet.

UserA and UserB are very confused because they don't know why.

Is this unavoidable?
Is there a solution?

With Ethereum tokens, I can transfer without problems even in the above cases.

If there is any mistake in my understanding, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

In Solana each wallet can have many accounts in a token but it's not possible in Ethereum, an account in Solana is like a file and a token is like a folder, if any wallet wants to have any space for its data storage, it should rent a file in the token's folder and that file is an associated account that belongs to that wallet

Answer (score 0):

I think by `non-associated` you mean UserB doesn't have a TokenX token account. Ie, UserB doesn't have what Solana would call a `associated token account` (also called ATA) for tokenX.

In your scenario, UserX tried to send UserB some TokenX, UserB didn't have a TokenX ATA, you recieved an error saying UserB didn't have a TokenX ATA.

- UserA wallet

  - UserA TokenX Associated Token Account
- UserB wallet

  - (no associated token accounts)

> If there is any mistake in my understanding, please point it out.

Sure - each users typically has just one wallets. **Token accounts (which are called 'token accounts' not 'Token Wallets' are made inside a users wallet.**

UserA can definitely send UserB token X, **UserA will pay a small amount of Sol to make a TokenX Token Account in UserB's wallet.** See `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount()` in web3.js if you're a programmer.

- UserA wallet

  - UserA TokenX Associated Token Account
- UserB wallet

  - UserB TokenX Associated Token Account

After UserB has a token account for TokenX, user A can then send them some TokenX tokens.